# How can I instantiate multiple instances of the same object in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, object, instantiation

With traditional OOP, I would (or could, rather) create a model / object that represents a `User`, with properties that reflect that, i.e., `name`, `id`, `job title`, etc.

I could then create a new instance of that object and assign it to a variable, and if I was looping through a result set, I could create an instance for each one. With CodeIgniter, this seems impossible, as doing:

```
$this->load->model('User');
```

Instantiates it, and places it for use at `$this->user`.

Isn't there any way to use models as objects in a more traditional manner? But without hacking the CodeIgniter way of doing things?

I understand that you can assign things to a different object name using `$this->load->model('User', 'fubar')`, but it's not as dynamic as simply assigning an instance to a variable.

---

Thanks for the answers guys. I think that I missed a vital part of working the "CodeIgniter Way", but I've just been looking through a contributed library, and the practice of using the same instance (assigned to the CodeIgniter namespace), but clearing the instance variables after each use, seems to be a great way to work that removes my reservations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use the `load()` functions. You can just use `require_once` and `new User()`, like you normally would.

Using the `load()` should only be for things you want in the global CodeIgniter namespace. As you can see, it gets polluted really quickly if you try to use it for everything.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i knew i could still do this, but wondered if there's something i could do to avoid using require(), and still use CI's loading. I.e. could i do: `$this->load->model('User');` then take copies with `$var = new $this->user` ?

Comment: Daniel: see the first item on this article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/6-codeigniter-hacks-for-the-masters/

Answer (score 0):

You can still instantiate objects in CodeIgniter the same way as you do it normally.

```
$user1 = new Users(); // Instantiate
$user2 = new Users();

$user1->property;     // Using it
$user2->method()

unset($user1);        // Unset it when done for good practice.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [what JustAnil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390764/how-can-i-instantiate-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object-in-codeigniter/8391019#8391019) and [minboost said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390764/how-can-i-instantiate-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object-in-codeigniter/8390999#8390999) are correct. However, standard practice for how the majority of CodeIgniter developers write code is with the following syntax

```
$this->mymodel->mymethod();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// User_model.php

public function get_users() {
    $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
    return $query->result();
}

// User_controller.php
public function show_users() {
    $data['users'] = $this->User_model->get_users();
    $this->load->view('show_users', $data);
}

// show_users.php  (view file)
$x = 0;
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $x = $user;
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: Yes thats what I thought, no relevance to this question.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8391130/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).